# Semantic Markup: Line Break After Link

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

I want to:

1. Display a series of links, each on a new line
2. Maintain the links' variable width and text-wrapping ability
3. Constrain the mouse-hover area of each link to its actual content
4. Keep the links inside of the content flow

The best solution I can think of is

```
<div>
    <a href="">Text</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="">Text</a>
</div>
```

, but I don't like adding the non-semantic `<div>`.  I tried using `a { float: left; clear: both }` , but that took the links out of the content flow.  To my knowledge, I can't use a pseudo-selector such as `:outer-wrapper`.  Is there a better solution, or are `<div>` wrappers the best solution?

*I thought of using `<ul><li><a>`, but I only have one or two links per page, and it doesn't seem resonable to add `<ul><li>` in place of `<div>` just to avoid a `<div>`

Comment: You could use `<br />`

Comment: How many items does it take to have a list of items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is largely an opinion-based and philosophy issue, a source of endless and useless debates over “semantic markup”, itself a semantically vague concept. But to turn the question to something more constructive, I would ask what it really matters which markup you use. What does it imply in non-CSS rendering, or when assistive software is used?

From this viewpoint, `ul` is OK if the default rendering, with bullets, is acceptable. Otherwise, use `div`, or use `br` between links. Do not try to use just `a` with styling, since then the links would by default run together, appearing as inline text with no separator.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the obvious `br` and reminding me to think of what the page looks like without the CSS applied

Answer (score 1):

Options could be:
*(to wrap them on their content)*

1. `display:table`, to stack them.
2. `display:inline-block` or,
3. `float:left` to have them on a line.

For the markup, you can wrap `<a>` into a `<nav>` tag. and add a role attribut to distinguished it from or for main-navigation.
http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#landmark_roles

Notes: If nav unneccessary any other tag could be used , such as footer or paragraph.
More here : http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-nav-element

Thx all

Comment: You should only use `nav` if the links are for the site/page navigation.

Comment: @GCyrillus You should specify this in your answer (this is some quite interesting add-on to your answer which I didn't know about) !

Comment: @GCyrillus: In what way "no"? [From the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element): "a section of a page that links to other pages or to parts within the page: a section with navigation links"

Comment: just edited my answer. i'll be listening, since english is not my mother language, i might misunderstands things :)

Comment: You are referring to WAI-ARIA roles. But no matter which ARIA role you use, you should still use the HTML elements according to the *HTML* spec.

Comment: Links aren't necessarily navigation.  A nav element is supposed to be for navigating within the section of the document it belongs to (pagination could be navigation, a link to the source of a quotation would not be).  You shouldn't have more than one nav element per section, but a subsection could have its own nav.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you want to put on a page, semantically, is a list of links. So use just that.

```
ul > li > a { /*whatever you want*/ }
```

You might consider [wrapping the list in a `nav`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-nav-element), or you could forget the `ul` altogether and have just

```
nav > a { display: block; }
```

Also, don't think all `divs`s are non-semantic. Yes, they don't have a specific meaning, but the spec says they represent their contents. A really great use for a `div` would be for grouping elements together that have the same theme or function. In your case, I wouldn't have a `div` that contains just one `a`, because you'd be right about the `div` serving as bloat.